# Is there a better way to set relationships in Grails?

Tags: grails, constructor

I'm starting to learn Grails, so this might be a noob question. My doubt is very simple, although I've searched and could not find the asnwer that I'm looking for.

Here's the problem:

I have a domain class that has a relationship with another domain class that I have, like this:

```
class Class3 {

    static belongsTo = [class1:Class1]

    (...)
}
```

And I'm creating an action inside my controller, that receives a JSON object from my Class3. Inside this JSON, I have an ID of a class1 object of mine.

The question is: how I properly create a instance of Class3, initilizing it's class1 property, only having the class1's Id and not an actual instance of it?

I'm now that I can look for`Class1.get(parsed_id)` like this (that's what I'm doing now, and it's working):

```
def jsonObj = request.JSON

def class3 = new Class3(class1: Class1.get(jsonObj.class1.id) (...))
class3.save(flush: true)
```

This what my json looks like:

```
{class1:{id:1} (...)}
```

But it I think that it's a little overhead to look in DB for this instance of class1 to initialize my class3 relationship and save it in my DB. Is there a better way to do this? Like, save the foreign key of class1 inside my class3 direcly in DB, without an extra `SELECT` ?

Or maybe it has a way of initializing a object from a JSON object?

Comment: So the goal is to not execute the "select class1" ?

Comment: Ideally yeah, in Ruby on Rails I can achieve this, because the class3 object would have a property `class1_id`, that I can set and save. I don't know if Grails has  something similar

Comment: Grails has a similar concept "class1Id", however it is read only. I tried a few things - nothing worked.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyways. Maybe its just impossible

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're doing on the json side of things, but generally, this is pretty easy.  The most basic would be the following.  Let's say you want to create a new Address belonging to a specific User:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="user.id" value="${user.id}" />
  <label>street:</label>
  <input type="text" name="street" />
  ....
</form>
```

When you submit the above form, the controller might look like this:

```
class AddressController {

   def save() {
     def address = new Address(params)
     address.save()
   }
}
```

When the form is passed into the controller, it passes in a map of params, one of which is:

```
user.id: 1234
```

Because of this, grails will automatically set an instance of User with an ID of 1234 on the Address object.  So when you do:

```
address.save()
```

The belongsTo relationship has been established.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I saw this in the `create()` method that scaffolds genereted in my controller. The problem is this constructor-like ( `new Address(params)` )works with this `params` that comes from a `HTML` form. I even tried to use the JSON in the constructor, but doesn't worked.

Comment: The problem, correct me if I'm wrong, isn't that the code isn't working. The OP wants to avoid a select statement for, in your case, `User`.

Comment: You are right, @James Kleeh. The code do works now, but my question is if there's a way to avoid a select in DB just to set the relationship. I edited my question to put more informations about the json

Comment: There is no loading of User from the database in my code example.  It doesn't need to be fetched.  I'm never getting the User when saving the address.

Comment: The problem is that your code is assuming the `address` object is comming from a HTML form. This does not work with JSON -> `def address = new Address(params)`

Comment: Yes it does.  I have an old project where we did it.  I'll see if I can drudge up an example.

Comment: If you really have, please post some example code, I would be glad.